# How do I set delete permission?

Tags: java, permissions

I'm writing a program, a part of which is to delete files in a certain folder (in root of program). Currently, the files are NOT created by the program, but externally - but in the future they may or may not be created/edited by the program itself.

Now the issue:

When I try to delete a file, I get permission exception. After a lot of checking, debugging and research, I wrote this code:

```
private void checkAndDelete(int n, String fileName) {
    // TODO: file permission error
    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        file.setWritable(true);
        SecurityManager s = new SecurityManager();
        s.checkDelete(fileName);
        System.out.println(file);
        if(file.delete()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deletion successful!");
            initializeNorth();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deletion failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

`n` is the value when user clicks yes or no in the dialog box confirming deletion, `fileName` is the file name.

Now, the `checkDelete` method throws this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "DB/fun trivia.kgf" "delete")
```

So I have narrowed the problem - permission problem. If it matters, I have the file in dropbox (where all my projects are). The file exists, is readable and writable. I've done all checks. The problem is only for permission.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: I tried to change location of my file to be on my local system, but it has the same error. So its not a problem while only on dropbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I hadn't closed my `Scanner` for the file. I was simply suppressing the resource leak.. I had to wrap my file `Scanner` in `try { } finally { }` for it to work though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, run your software as administrator.
You can run your program as administrator or the IDE itself (Netbeans, Eclipse). Both should work.

Comment: I always run as admin. But the issue is that even though I can run it as admin, the other person using the program may not.

Comment: Hmm, ok! Do you really need a Security Policy on the application? Is there any possibility to remove SecurityManager?

Comment: I added the `SecurityManager` just for debugging. I do not need it for my program to work.

Comment: Try to run as admin and remove these lines: 
SecurityManager s = new SecurityManager();
s.checkDelete(fileName);